# problem with "TypeError: '<' not supported"

Tags: python

So I am trying to re-learn some python by myself and a task wants me to make a list and put the elements that are less than 5 into another list,

```
a = []
b = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
for element in b:
    if ( b < 5 ):
        a.append(b)
print (a)
```

Comment: you want to compare `element<5`  and do `a.append(element)`

Comment: Do you really mean `if element < 5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` is the list here; `element` is the single element you're using in iteration.

```py
for element in b:
    if element < 5:
        a.append(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the entire list instead of the individual elements
Try:

```
if element < 5
```